# Rails DON'T sanitize

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, sanitize, ace-editor

I am making a web app that integrates the Ace online IDE. A user enters an input through the Ace IDE which is then stored in a database. But when that is then rendered from the database Rails has done some sort of sanitization and the HTML tags are not loaded.

How do I explicitly tell Rails to leave all HTML tags in the tags and not format it (includes tabs and spaces)?

EDIT:

This is what the user inputs:

[image]

And this is what it outputs:

[image]

Comment: This question needs more details. Show us, for example, the template that renders the HTML with the missing tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it was because I was using `simple_format()` when I removed that and just simply called `<%= @lesson.lesson_content %>` it rendered perfectly.

Comment: are you sure that it is actually returning `<` and not `&lt;` ? (they might look the same depending on how ace handles things under the covers).

Comment: @masukomi yes I am sure, I tested it by rendering it in a plain div. It renders the full text in "" speech marks so the browser reads it literally as a string not HTML.

Answer (score 2):

Try the [raw](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/OutputSafetyHelper/raw) method. This method outputs without escaping a string

Answer (score 1):

you have to append `.html_safe` to any string you're returning to the view. By default Rails doesn't trust anything the user might have created.

So

```
 <%= @my_source_code_from_the_db %>
```

Becomes

```
<%= @my_source_code_from_the_db.html_safe %>
```

As @Sam_D mentioned, another option is to wrap your string in a call to raw:

```
<%= raw(@my_source_code_from_the_db) %>
```